# Trouble with marking and selecting the list view

Tags: android

In my application I am having a list view,Now the problem is I want to get the marked positions 
the code I am using is

```
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Entered Delete Button");
                String selected = "";
                int cntChoice = lv.getCount();
                System.out.println("The Number Of Contacts"+cntChoice);
                SparseBooleanArray x = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
                System.out.println(x);
                for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){
                    if(x.get(i)) {
                        selected += lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";  

                    }
                }   
                Toast.makeText(ViewSelectedContacts.this, 
                        selected, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

The problem is SparseBooleanArray is not populating with the element
Also i had added

```
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
```

in the listview..Somebody please help me to fin the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Try this code (works for me):

// MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       final ListView listTags = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPack);
       listTags.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, mStrings));
       listTags.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                   int position, long id) {
               listTags.setSelection(position);
//               Toast.makeText(getParent(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });



    }


     private String[] mStrings = {

        "Comte", "Coolea", "Cooleney", "Coquetdale", "Corleggy", "Cornish Pepper",
        "Cotherstone", "Cotija", "Cottage Cheese", "Cottage Cheese (Australian)",
        "Cougar Gold", "Coulommiers", "Coverdale", "Crayeux de Roncq", "Cream Cheese",
        "Cream Havarti", "Crema Agria", "Crema Mexicana", "Creme Fraiche", "Crescenza",
        "Croghan", "Crottin de Chavignol", "Crottin du Chavignol", "Crowdie", "Crowley",
        "Cuajada", "Curd", "Cure Nantais", "Curworthy", "Cwmtawe Pecorino",
       };

// Main xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listPack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

// list_item.xml // layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: No I want to find the trouble in my code, the thing is i want to mark few items in the listview and delete it

Comment: read this, this is deleting selected items
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: if any issue then give me ur id i will mail u

Comment: bro i mail you a example , i have made it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24178/discussion-between-rohit-and-ammukuttylive)